# SMS Delivery reports in Ice cream sandwich dont show up

Tags: sms

After I send a message I used to get a delivery report confirming the delivery of a SMS message in my old (non-Android) phone.

But in my Intex Ibuddy Connect with Android 4.0.4 I am not getting the notification of delivery.

I have checked the option for the delivery report in the settings still, no change.

What could be the issue?

Comment: @Sid **None of them worked** for me(at least on my Tab) so I can't mark any of them....
Answers may be right on other tabs....but I can't confirm that...so....

P.S. But I can Up vote for your effort though.... :)

Comment: Alright then. Will update the answer if I get some other options for you. :)

Comment: none of them worked for my galaxy s2 plus.. did you get any wrkin solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

In android, (particularly in ICS), you don't get a pop up delivery notification as the ordinary phones. Instead there will be a `tick` in front of the date of your message. That's the maximum delivery notification you get.

[image: ScreenCap]

If you *really* need some bigger notification, you can use an apps like [Delivery Reports](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.droida.deliveryreports&hl=en), [Delivery Reporter+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_jessssser.DeliveryReporter_PLUS), [Messaging Notification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.jgui.android.test.sms.rx), etc.

Comment: I am not getting that tick either....even after I have had a conversion of about 10-15 messages both ways with another guy...

Comment: @SangeetMenon Then try the app suggested. If it gives you notifications, there is a problem with your messaging app

Comment: any other app other than this...this one is not compatible with my tab...

Comment: @SangeetMenon See the edit please.

Comment: @Sid...its strange but none of the applications are compatible for my tab..

Comment: can you try using something like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.tabletsms&hl=en) then?

Comment: How is it shown if it is pending then? Just no icon?

Answer (score 1):

Delivery reports are operator (sender and receiver) dependent feature. This will be successful only if both cooperates (usually happens). My operator BSNL is quite unreliable especially to the SMSs sent to international numbers. Several times it has happened for me - I would have not received a delivery report where as the receiver would have replied to my SMS!

I would suggest to follow these steps to ensure that the options are set correctly:

1. Make sure the delivery report option is ticked. In my LGP500 the user interface is quite confusing if you are in a hurry. Make sure the delivery report option is set for SMS and not for MMS - I fell for this quite a few times when ever I do factory reset.
2. Set the validity period to `maximum`.
3. Try sending a test SMS to a phone number of the same operator of yours and it will be helpful, if you can ensure the delivery yourself - like getting a reply from the receiver.

As @Sid said, the delivery reports are just seen as a small glyph like this:
[image]
In my phone, I also get a toast message (a message saying `delivered` for few seconds). On long press on the message I had sent, I will have an option `view report` which will give the status as `failure/pending/delivered`.